# interservice communication using grpc in quarkus

Tags: microservices, grpc, quarkus, mutiny

Is there any sample code / help for inter service communication using grpc in quarkus.
We have 2 services. we want to expose one service api to other service.
I have included all the dependency and I have created proto file, i have to keep protofile in both client and server? or we have to make common project to store proto file and communicate both service from there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following documentation and examples:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-getting-started
- https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-service-implementation
- https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-service-consumption
- Example: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/grpc-plain-text-quickstart
- Example: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/grpc-tls-quickstart
- https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-grpc/

One important aspect is that with gRPC what you share is the proto file. So yes, you will either duplicate it or package it in a shared artifact.